# In a group $G$, prove that if $bab^{-1} = a^r$ then $b^j a b^{-j} = a^{r^j}$

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group, $a,b \in G$ and $bab^{-1} = a^r$ for some $r \in \mathbb{N}$, then $b^j a b^{-j} = a^{r^j}$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

I couldn't find my way out of this question.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: By induction on $j$.

Comment: how can I conclude without commutativity?

Comment: You don't need commutativity to insert e everywhere and rewrite it as $b^{-1}b$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}
b^{j+1}ab^{-j-1} &= bb^{j}ab^{-j}b^{-1} \\
&= b a^{r^j}b^{-1} \\
&= (bab^{-1})^{{r^j}} \\
&= (a^r)^{r^{j}} \\
&=a^{r^{j+1}}.
\end{align}$$
Here we used the induction hypothesis $b^{j}ab^{-j} = a^{r^j }$ for the second equality . As you see you don't need commutativity.

Comment: Just to note, in the OP’s question, the base case is not necessarily $r=1$, so to be complete, you would want to run the inductive step in two directions.

Comment: We're doing the induction on $j$.

Comment: Good answer! How do you prove that $bab^{-j}=bab^{-1}$ for all $j\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: But we cannot conclude that this is a Property of Groups then, am I right? It's just a case in an exercise. (though I see no special condition.) Can you correct me?